# Struts2 jquery autocompleter with JSON

Tags: json, jquery, struts2

I'm using atocompleter in my form with json.
This is the part of my struts.xml

```
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">

    <action name="jsonSample" class="com.jaisar.jsep.product.web.action.DatabaseJSON" method="getDatabaseJSONData" >
         <result type="json"/>
    </action>
</package>
```

My jsp page is :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts2-jquery-tags"%>

<s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonSample.action"/>
    <sj:select
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    id="echo"
    name="echo"
    list="languageList"
    emptyOption="true"
    headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="Please Select a Language"/>
```

Action class method is :

```
public class DatabaseJSON  extends ActionSupport {
    private List<String> languageList;
public String getDatabaseJSONData()  {
        languageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        languageList.add("Java");
        languageList.add("PHP");
        languageList.add("C#");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
// Setters and getters for languageList .. 
}
```

But the page doesn't load with the autocompleter. Page shows simply a select box... Any solutions? Plz ... I refered a lot , but i couln't find the silution...

I referred the site http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag#Receive_Entrys_from_a_simple_String_List

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please check with Firebug if your json call is successfully.

Comment: @Zemzela He can use any method name he wants as long as he configures it in his action mapping which obviously he has. And `success` is the default result name so it doesn't need to be explicitly declared.

Comment: @Zemzela  I checked json values in browser using firebug... When i place  the url **http://localhost:8090/jsep/jsonSample.action** in browser, it displays values like {"databaseJSONData":"success","languageList":["Java","PHP","C#"]} ... But these values are not populated in select box.... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the result name in your struts.xml.  Try: `<result name="success" type="json">`

Comment: i specified it... But values are not populated in select box.... I checked json values in browser using firebug... When i place  the url **http://localhost:8090/jsep/jsonSample.action** in browser, it displays values like {"databaseJSONData":"success","languageList":["Java","PHP","C#"]} ... But these values are not populated in select box.... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting `dataType='json'` attribute in the `sj:select` tag.

Comment: I checked json values in browser using firebug... When i place  the url **http://localhost:8090/jsep/jsonSample.action** in browser, it displays values like {"databaseJSONData":"success","languageList":["Java","PHP","C#"]} ... But these values are not populated in select box.... Thanks in advance...